# Is it possible to assign a select field to a variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, variable-assignment

I have to get a value from a select and create a variable to use in a insert, is it possible in PostgreSQL? I can't create a function because my hosting don't allow this.

Here is the table creation schema:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE identificador_produto START 1;

CREATE TABLE product (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('identificador_produto') primary key,
    description varchar(60) not null
);

CREATE TABLE material (
    product_id integer DEFAULT nextval('identificador_produto') primary key,
    description varchar(60) not null
);
```

Example to ilustrate what i need:

```
begin;

    select currval('identificador_produto') as id;

    insert into material (product_id, description) values (id, 'Gold');
    insert into material (product_id, description) values (id, 'Silver');
    insert into material (product_id, description) values (id, 'Wood');
    insert into material (product_id, description) values (id, 'Steel');
    insert into material (product_id, description) values (id, 'Water');
    insert into material (product_id, description) values (id, 'Paper');

commit;
```

I have to assign the 'id' value to a variable and them use it to do some inserts in the same transaction, but the inserts share the same sequence of 'product', because of this i can't use the curval() function, otherwise each insert will get a different id.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I think your understanding of `currval` is wrong. `currval`  will return the last *generated* id that was taken from your sequence.

The following will insert all rows with the same id:

```
insert into material (product_id, description) 
values (nextval('identificador_produto'), 'Gold');

insert into material 
(product_id, description) 
values 
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'Silver');

insert into material 
(product_id, description) 
values 
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'Wood');

insert into material 
(product_id, description) 
values 
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'Steel');

insert into material 
(product_id, description) 
values 
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'Water');

insert into material 
(product_id, description) 
values 
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'Paper');
```

The first one generates a **new** ID and the subsequent `INSERT`s re-use **that same id**. This is transaction safe and will work correctly even when thousands of connections do this (that's the beauty of sequences)

But I think your table design is wrong. The way you defined the tables, you could just move the description column to the product table.

My guess is that you actually want something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE identificador_produto START 1;

CREATE TABLE product (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('identificador_produto') primary key,
    description varchar(60) not null
);

CREATE TABLE material (
    material_id serial primary key,
    product_id integer not null 
       references product(id),
    description varchar(60) not null
);
```

Which means you have one or more rows in material that reference a specific product. The insert pattern would then look something like this:

```
insert into product
(description) 
values 
('foobar');

insert into material 
(product_id, description)
values
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'silver');

insert into material 
(product_id, description)
values
(currval('identificador_produto'), 'gold');
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a variable for that:

```
insert into material (product_id, description) values (
    (select id from product where condition = 100)
    , 'Gold');
```

Comment: The problem is because i am getting this 'id' from a sequence, like this: "select currval('identificador_produto');" and the inserts use the same sequence, so i can't use the select inside insert because it will return a different 'id' for each insert

Comment: @masimao: then just use the `curval()` call again in the insert statements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, The tables 'product' and 'material' share the same sequence in yours primary keys, so if i call curval() in each insert, each one will get a different id code and the insert won't reffer the correct registry that was returnet by select.

Comment: @masimao: `currval()` returns the last *generated* id, it will **not** fetch a new value from the sequence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Please see the post again, i've been updated it explaing about the sequence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks for your help! I've gott a solution based on your answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do both inserts with the same id value, in the same transaction, this might be a good alternative:

```
WITH x(descr) AS (VALUES ('Gold'), ('Silver'))
INSERT INTO material (product_id, description)
  SELECT id, descr
    FROM x,
        (SELECT id FROM product WHERE condition = 100) y;
```

The other possibility, if you really need imperative code with variables, is a DO construct:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, first declare a variable in the declare section.

Then say "select id into variable from product where condition = 100;" and continue

```
    declare
    myvar int;
    begin
    select id into myvar from product where condition = 100;

    ...
    end;
```

Comment: Can you give me a example, please? Sorry, but i am newbie using 'declare'.

Comment: The application has a lot of users, do you know if is dangerous occur errors due the 'myvar' duplication? Because is possible that it will be created by different users at the same time.